# Recursive algorithm for power of a power

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

I need to calculate power of a power. For example: 3^2^n . You can think n as input but this example is not the same thing as 9^n. I write a algorithm using loops but now I need to write recursive one. I couldn't find an efficient way to write it.

Comment: Is `n` always a positive integer?

Comment: Yes, it is a positive integer

Comment: Can you please allaborate? We can't do 9^n. Can we do 3^(2n) ?

Comment: To clarify: you want to evaluate 3^(2^n)?

Comment: @Henry that's right. You can do 3^(2^n). If n is 4, then it is 3^16

Comment: You need to express f(n) using f(n-1)

Comment: And where are you stuck? Can you add your initial tryout, even if it is way off the direction?

Comment: *"I couldn't find an efficient way to write it."* not an efficient way, or couldn't find a way at all ...?

Comment: If you have an algorithm using loops, you should post it: [edit] your question. It might be easy to convert it to a recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say x^(y^n) = `powpow(x, y, n)` with y and n >= 1

If y > 1 and n > 1, `powpow(x, y, n) = powpow(x, y, 1) * powpow(x, y, n-1)` (getting closer to the result)

If y > 1 and n = 1, `powpow(x, y, 1) =  x * powpow(x, y-1, 1)` (getting closer)

If y = 1 and n = 1, `powpow(x, 1, 1) = x` (solved)

That's less efficient than a loop, but it's recursive. Is that what you're aiming for ...?

**EDIT** as @pjs has pointed out, the first case should be:
`powpow(x, y, 1) =  powpow(x, powpow(y, n, 1), 1)`

Comment: The `y > 1 && n >1` case expressed mathematically is `x^y * x^(y^(n-1))`, which equates to `x^(y + y^(n-1))` rather than the desired outcome `x^(y * y^(n-1))`.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and implemented this in Ruby, which is pretty darn close to pseudocode and has the added benefit of being testable.  Since Ruby also has arbitrary precision integer arithmetic, the following code works with non-trivial arguments.

This implementation is based on the old trick of squaring the base and raising it to half the specified power when the exponent is even, so the recursive stack grows logarithmically rather than linearly in powers.  This was inspired by Ilya's answer, but I found that the `y > 1 and n > 1` case is not correct, leading me to use the recursive call within a recursive call implemented in the `elif n > 1` line below:

```
def powpow(x, y, n)
  if y == 0
    return 1
  elsif y == 1 || n == 0
    return x
  elsif n > 1
    return powpow(x, powpow(y, n, 1), 1)
  elsif y.even?
    return powpow(x * x, y / 2, 1)
  else
    return x * powpow(x * x, y / 2, 1)
  end
end

p powpow(3,2,5)   # => 1853020188851841
```

I was able to confirm that result directly:

```
irb(main):001:0> 2**5
=> 32
irb(main):002:0> 3**32
=> 1853020188851841
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Power {
    int ans = 1;
    int z = 1;
    int x = 1;

    int pow1(int b, int c) {
        if (c > 1) {
            pow1(b, c - 1);
        }
        ans = ans * b;
        return ans;
    }

    void pow(int a, int b, int c) {
        x = pow1(b, c);
        ans = a;
        pow1(a, x - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Power p = new Power();
        p.pow(3, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(p.ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to add a few lines of description to your answer. Why have you chosen this algorithm, what are pros and cons of it, etc.

Comment: For the question as (x^(y^n)), I tried to implement recursion for (y^n) first and then used the answer of val=(y^n) to again implement recursion for (x^val).

Answer (score 0):

**Reccursive Approach**

We can compute power(x, y) efficiently in complexity O(log y) using the following reccurnce :

```
power(x, y) : 
   if y is 0 : return 1

   if y is even :
       return square( power(x, y / 2))
   else :
       return square( power(x, (y - 1) / 2 ) * x
```

Using [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) we can compute the complexity of above procedure to be O(log y) (Similar case as that of binary search.)

Now, if we use the above procedure to compute 3 ^ (2 ^ n).

We can see that (2 ^ n) will be computed in O(log n) and 3 ^ k. Where k = 2 ^ n, will be computed in O(log k) = O(log (2 ^ n)) = O(n).

So using the binary exponentiation trick sequentially we can solve this using a complexity of O(n).

**Iterative approach**

Idea : Suppose we have calculated 3 ^ (2 ^ x). Then we can easily calculated 3 ^ (2 ^ (x + 1)) by just squaring 3 ^ (2 ^ x) as :

```
( 3 ^ (2 ^ x) ) * ( 3 ^ (2 ^ x) ) =  3 ^ ( (2 ^ x) + (2 ^ x) )
                                  =  3 ^ ( 2 * (2 ^ x) )
                                  =  3 ^ ( (2 ^ (x + 1) )
```

So, if we start with 3 ^ (2 ^ 0), in n steps we can reach on to 3 ^ (2 ^ n) :

```
def solve(n):
    ans = 3 ^ (2 ^ 0) = 3
    for i in range(0, n) :
        ans = square(ans)
    return ans
```

Clearly the complexity of the above solution is also **O(n)**.